# Sklearn cosine_similarity convert 1D array to 2D array in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, cosine-similarity

I am learning natural language processing and using the nltk module and scikit learn module in Python. I wanted to first look at how existing codes work before I wrote my own. So I looked online for chatbots that were built on these libraries and I found one on github.
I downloaded a github code for a chatbot which uses Scikit learn and nltk modules. This is the code for that

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys
import nltk
import pyprind
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity 

SYNSETS = joblib.load('blobs/SYNSETS.pkl')
TAGS_HASH = joblib.load('blobs/TAGS_HASH.pkl')
data = pd.read_csv('data/friends-final.txt', sep='\t')
triturns = joblib.load('blobs/triturns.pkl')
filtered_triturns = joblib.load('blobs/filtered.pkl')
all_tags = ['CC', 'CD', 'DT', 'EX', 'FW', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR', 'JJS', 'LS', 'MD',
       'NN', 'NNS', 'NNP', 'NNPS', 'PDT', 'POS', 'PRP', 'PRP$', 'RB',
       'RBR', 'RBS', 'RP', 'SYM', 'TO', 'UH', 'VB', 'VBD', 'VBG', 'VBN',
       'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT', 'WP', 'WP$', 'WRB']

def get_synsets(text):
    if not text in SYNSETS:
        sent = nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(text))
        chunks = nltk.ne_chunk(sent, binary=False)
        s = set()
        def add_synsets(synsets):
            for synset in synsets:
                s.add(synset)
        for c in chunks:
            if hasattr(c, 'node'):
                if c.node == 'PERSON':
                    add_synsets(wn.synsets('person', pos=wn.NOUN))
                elif c.node == 'ORGANIZATION':
                    add_synsets(wn.synsets('organization', pos=wn.NOUN))                
                elif c.node == 'GPE':
                    add_synsets(wn.synsets('place', pos=wn.NOUN))
                elif c.node == 'LOCATION':
                    add_synsets(wn.synsets('location', pos=wn.NOUN))
                elif c.node == 'FACILITY':
                    add_synsets(wn.synsets('facility', pos=wn.NOUN))
                elif c.node == 'GSP':
                    add_synsets(wn.synsets('group', pos=wn.NOUN))                
                else:
                    print c, c.node, c.leaves()
            elif c[1][:2] in ['VB', 'JJ', 'ADV', 'NN']:
                pos = {'VB': wn.VERB, 'NN': wn.NOUN, 'ADV': wn.ADV, 'JJ': wn.ADJ}[c[1][:2]]
                add_synsets(wn.synsets(c[0], pos=pos))
            else:
                add_synsets(wn.synsets(c[0]))
        SYNSETS[text] = set([x.name for x in s])
    return SYNSETS[text]

def sem_sim(s1, s2):
    ss1 = get_synsets(s1)
    ss2 = get_synsets(s2)
    if ss1 == ss2:
        return 1
    return 2*len(ss1.intersection(ss2)) / (len(ss1) + len(ss2))

def cos_sim(s1, s2):
    d = [{}, {}]
    for p in all_tags:
        d[0][p] = d[1][p] = 0
    for i,s in enumerate([s1, s2]):
        if not s in TAGS_HASH:
            TAGS_HASH[s] = nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(s))
        tags = TAGS_HASH[s]
        for t in tags:
            if t[1] in d[i]:
                d[i][t[1]] += 1
    return cosine_similarity([d[0][p] for p in all_tags], [d[1][p] for p in all_tags])[0][0] #ERROR OCCURS HERE

def sim(s1, s2, alpha=0.7):
    return alpha*sem_sim(s1, s2) + (1-alpha)*cos_sim(s1, s2) #ERROR OCCURS HERE

def get_response(msg):
    best_val = 0
    best = None
    bar = pyprind.ProgBar(len(filtered_triturns), monitor=True)
    for t in filtered_triturns:
        question = t[0]
        answer = t[1]
        val = sim(msg, question)
        if (val > best_val):# or (val == best_val and len(answer) < len(msg))):
            best = answer
            best_val = val
        bar.update()
    return best

def main():
    while True:
        msg = raw_input('--> ')
        print get_response(msg)
        sys.stdout.flush()

def filter_triturns(thresh=0.7):
    L = []
    bar = pyprind.ProgBar(len(triturns), monitor=True)
    for i,tt in enumerate(triturns):
        a = data.irow(tt)['line']
        b = data.irow(tt+1)['line']
        c = data.irow(tt+2)['line']
        if sem_sim(a, b) > thresh:
            L.append([a,b])
        if sem_sim(b, c) > thresh:
            L.append([c,b])
        bar.update()
    return L

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But upon running this code I get an error :

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

The error occurs at the the line `return cosine_similarity([d[0][p] for p in all_tags], [d[1][p] for p in all_tags])[0][0]` and the line below it(marked the said lines with # in the code above)

It is basically asking me to give a 2D array instead of 1D array which I tried doing but that doesn't seem to work. I am fairly new to sklearn so I don't exactly understand at which point do I put the code inside the square brackets.

Converting a 1D array like [abc] to a 2D array follows the process [ [abc] ] but in this case where do I do it?

I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change it over the cosine_similarity calculation, just change

```
cosine_similarity([d[0][p] for p in all_tags], [d[1][p] for p in all_tags])[0][0]
```

to

```
cosine_similarity([[d[0][p] for p in all_tags]], [[d[1][p] for p in all_tags]])[0][0]
```

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility is to use the `.reshape()` function